# Identificação de troca de guia

Tags: javascript, html5

Como sabem, um usuário quando acessa a internet ele sempre vai querer acessar varias guias ao mesmo tempo, youtube, facebook, email, etc, ele fica com uma guia sendo visualizada enquanto as outras ficam a sua disposição.
Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade do código identificar quando o usuário estar com a guia do nosso site visualizada e quando ela estar apenas como aba no navegador.

Answer (score 1):

Tem sim, para fazer isso você pode usar **Page Visibility API**. É bem simples você pode atrelar um evento do **document** e ele será disparado quando o usuário mudar de aba. Veja esse código bem simples que fiz para exemplificar :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Visible</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
   if( document.visibilityState == 'hidden'){
    document.body.innerHTML = "Saiu da minha página :(";
   }
 });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Esse é bem simples e detecta quando o usuário saiu, quando isso acontecer escreve a string **Saiu da minha página :(**.

Basta adicionat o **visibilitychange** e daí verificar o atributo **visibilityState** do **document**. Ele poder ter os seguintes retornos :

- visible : O conteúdo da página pode ser pelo menos parcialmente visível. Na prática, isso significa que a página é a aba de primeiro plano de uma janela não minimizada.
- hidden : O conteúdo da página não é visível para o usuário. Na prática, isso significa que o documento é uma guia de fundo ou parte de uma janela minimizada, ou o bloqueio de tela do SO está ativo.
- prerender : O conteúdo da página está sendo renderizado e não é visível para o usuário (considerado escondido para fins de document.hidden). O documento pode começar neste estado, mas nunca irá transitar para ele de outro valor. Nota: o suporte do navegador é opcional.
- unloaded : A página está sendo descarregada da memória. Nota: o suporte do navegador é opcional.

Você pode também de um jeito mais direto usar o **document.hidden** que retorna true ou false. Sendo true quando a aba da sua página estiver ativa ou false caso contrário.

Exemplo do uso de **document.hidden**.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
   if(document.hidden){
    document.body.innerText = "Volte :(";
   }
 });
});
```

Espero ter ajudado, para mais detalhes veja : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Answer (score 0):

Acho que pra verificar se a aba está ativa, apenas com plugins pro navegador, mas alternativamente, você pode usar os eventos de `focus` da janela:

```
var interval_id;
$(window).focus(function() {
    if (!interval_id)
        interval_id = setInterval(hard_work, 1000);
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    clearInterval(interval_id);
    interval_id = 0;
});
```

Como é dito [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active) resposta do SO em inglês.

Outra alternativa é usar a [visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API), que funciona mais ou menos da seguinte maneira:

```
var vis = (function(){
    var stateKey, eventKey, keys = {
        hidden: "visibilitychange",
        webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
        mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
        msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
    };
    for (stateKey in keys) {
        if (stateKey in document) {
            eventKey = keys[stateKey];
            break;
        }
    }
    return function(c) {
        if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
        return !document[stateKey];
    }
})();
```

Uso:

```
var visible = vis(); // dá o estado atual da aba

vis(aFunction);      // define um event handler para a troca de visibilidade
```